# AppsFlyer deep link issue

Tags: ios, redirect, deep-linking

I have trouble with AppsFlyer OneLink. On device it works some time (redirect to app, if app installed) and after some manipulation (don't know how to trigger it) link redirecting only to the App Store, even if app installed (checked on 2 devices).  I will be appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolve this problem by holding the link, and  in alert menu open app, not browser. It's not obvious. I didn't know that this option was.

Comment: I wants to open specific page using one link ? how it can be done ? any idea ?

Comment: @Mohit are you want to open specific page in App?